# Cannot Open xaml.cs File in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to open a `.xaml.cs` file in Visual Studio 2012, but double-clicking the file does nothing and right-clicking and selecting `Open` does nothing.

If I attempt to open any other `.xaml.cs` file, it works fine - so it is isolated to a single file.

For example...

- ImportUserControl.xaml - Opens fine
- ImportUserControl.xaml.cs - Won't open
- ExportUserControl.xaml - Opens fine
- ExportUserControl.xaml.cs - Won't open

I have also tried opening the `.xaml` file in Visual Studio and selecting `View Code` too.

What could cause this and how do I resolve it?

Comment: Sometimes VS2012 can flake-out like that. Have you tried right-clicking from the XAML view and selecting 'View Code'? Also excluding and then immediately including the xaml.cs file(s) again can get it to open up too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution to this isn't great, but I guess it is obvious.

I closed Visual Studio and then re-opened it. This cleared the problem up.